# Are there any cons to use a T-fitting into two ball valves instead of one combinated (Y-valve or similar) valve?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I was just wondering, because I could not find a cheap combinated valve (not from the US) for my sink and washing machine hoses and all of those I found, even tho they were overpriced, were not even ball valves.

So this route is much cheaper, but what matters to me the most is if there is any negatives to this approach (or if its possible at all for my case)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking to be able to independently turn the water off for the sink or the washer. The only issue you could have with a T is running water past the right angle connecting pipe. If you do this run water line in into the singular and let it split out to the other two ends that are in line with each other. (See the picture below)

The reason for this set up is what is the siphoning effect , as fluid passes the singular it will have a tendency to create a suction - siphoning water from that line , also no resistance one way could allow more water to flow in one direction (unrestricted) and not flow in the other - so if you follow this rule as per the picture - you should not have any issue.

[image: Water Flow in TEE]

Comment: Hey, I actually bought all the parts, except I could not find a straight quarter valve for home use (sink, washing machine or dishwasher).

So I am thinking of buying two of these: https://i.imgur.com/jfmyP1j.jpg

And do a system like this: https://i.imgur.com/qQoec0F.png

Will this work the same, or it will work flawlessly but will have a tad less water pressure than the other?

Comment: @appwizcpl - you will be fine with your example - the feed in pipe is the same; the outlets are a bit different in size but essentially the feed pipe to them is the same size - the difference should be negligible.

Comment: yes, but sadly there is no way around that, they must be different in size as I need one for the sink and the other for the washing machine. ;/

One last thing, this picture https://i.imgur.com/qQoec0F.png is from above point of view, and if the pipe is coming from the wall horizontally, the valves end pointing straight horizontal too. From convenience sake, for me is better to have the sink valve pointing upwards, the washing machine downwards, how big of a problem is that? 

Or what is the recommended pointing, upwards I guess not, but downwards or straight as I linked in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

I think a tee into two ball valves is exactly what you want here, for both the hot and cold. You can then shut off the water to the washing machine hoses when you're not washing (always a good idea) while still having water at the sink. Alternatively you could have one ball valve, then a tee connecting to both the sink and, through another ball valve, to the washing machine hose.

I've never seen a Y-valve used in this situation.